# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, codec, utf

```py
import os
import shutil
import codecs


directory = '~/Desktop/ra/clean_tokenized/1987'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    full_name = directory + '/' + filename
    with open(full_name, 'r') as article:
        for line in article:
            print(line)
```

Here's the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "~/Desktop/corpus_filter/01_corpus.py", line 11, in 
>       for line in article:
>     File "~/.conda/envs/MangerRA/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte

The file contains Japanese characters and I'm just trying make a CSV file with all the words that have come up in the files. But I can't get over this error.

Answer (score 1):

Python is trying to open your file using the UTF-8 encoding (which is the default most of the time these days). Unfortunately, your file is using some other encoding (or is otherwise corrupted), and so the decoding fails.

Unfortunately, I can't tell what encoding your file uses. You'll have to investigate that yourself. You might try another encoding like Shift JIS (using `open(full_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis')`), and see if you get valid text or [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

If all else fails, you can open the file in binary mode (`'rb'` rather than just `'r'`), and check out what is located at byte 3131 and immediately afterwards. It may be just a messed up bit of data in the file that you can delete or fix manually.

Comment: I checked the char-set of the file, and it says its in utf-8. How would I check what is located at byte 3131? thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Open in binary mode, then `read()` the whole file (or a big chunk of it) into a bytestring. Then just index or slice. `file.read()[3100:3200]` maybe...

Comment: Your answer might benefit from mentioning something like [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) as another attempt at guessing encodings.